# How is functional value defined?

Tags: tensors

"Suppose $\phi$ is a function of the coordinates $x^k$, and let denote $\bar{\phi}$ the functional value under a transformation to a new set of coordinates $\bar{x}^k$. Then $\phi$ is called a scalar or invariant with respect to the coordinate transformation if $\phi=\bar{\phi}$. A scalar or invariant is also called a tensor of rank zero."

Maybe this is obvious but the term "functional value" has not been defined anywhere in the book. I don't know what it means and therefore don't understand the definition.

The definition is from "Schaum's Outline of Vector Analysis", chapter 8.

Comment: I suggest you read Loomis and Sternberg's advanced calculus text. In particular Chapter 9 on differentiable manifolds, and even more specifically, section 9.2 (functions, convergence). I think this idea is clearly explained there.

Answer (score 1):

A functional is a function that takes a vector as input and gives a number as output.  A functional value is the value of the functional when you plug in a vector.  They are saying that if you get the same number in different coordinate systems, it is a "tensor of rank zero."

Comment: Here the term "functional value" doesn't mean the value of a covector on a vector. It's an admittedly confusing way of phrasing (since not everything is made explicit) that for a function $f:M\to \Bbb{R}$ defined on a manifold, and given two charts $(U,x),(V,\bar{x})$, if we define $f_x:= f\circ x^{-1}$ and $f_{\bar{x}}:= f\circ (\bar{x})^{-1}$ then $f_x\circ x= f_{\bar{x}}\circ \bar{x}$.